# Why iCloud tabs not working iOS 11 iPhone and iOS 10 iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, icloud

Unable to see iCloud tabs on iPad (safari).

Tried signing out and in of iCloud on iPad. I can see iCloud tabs on iPhone from iPad.

iPhone on iOS 11 but iPad is too old to update from iOS 10. Does the feature not work if the devices are on different OS’s?

Comment: Are both devices running the latest possible version of iOS (iOS 11.1.2 and iOS 10.3.3)? I would ensure that iCloud is signed in on both devices, and that Safari is enabled in the iCloud preference of both.

Comment: Both fully updated and have everything on in iCloud settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve concluded that iCloud tabs don’t work on older OS’s (when other devices are on newer ones).

Answer (score -1):

They put it into Reading List whereas before it was at the bottom of tabs open on the iPhone.

Comment: I don’t really understand your answer, I still see iCloud tabs on my phone the same way and I don’t see the relevance to the outdated OS on my iPad. Do you have a source/screen shot/further explanation?